# Android Search Query and Sort in order

Tags: android, sqlite, search

Anyone has an idea how this is done? I have a regular search query below that displays matching data in a listview, i tried putting COLUMN NAME + " ASC" at the order part, but i got errors.

```
                public Cursor getSearch(String query)
            {
                SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
                Cursor c = db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, ALL_KEYS, KEY_NAME + " LIKE ?",
                        new String[] {"%"+ query+ "%" }, null, null, null,
                        null);

                if(c != null)
                {
                c.moveToFirst();
                }
                return c;
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'Order by' clause should be the 8th argument in the query call:

```
Cursor c = db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, ALL_KEYS, KEY_NAME + " LIKE ?",
                    new String[] {"%"+ query+ "%" }, null, null, COLUMN_NAME + " ASC", null);
```

See: [Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query%28boolean,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

Comment: I thought i tried that already, can't believe i didn't. thx :)